# what would be the database URL of the mysql database that we access through phpMyAdmin?

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am writing a code that access a MySql database. The database is on a server that we access through our web-browser

Let's say,

> `URL: http://cbm.goo.com/phpMyAdmin`
>
> `Username: username`
>
> `Password: password`

The above username and password are used to access the MySql database through a web-browser.

`Q1.` What would be database url of the database to be used in `JDBC` programming?

I tried the following url but it didn't work

> `jdbc:mysql://cbm.goo.com:3306/scores?user=username&password=password`

========================== Edited ===================================

I am getting the following error:

> `Communications link failure`
>
> `The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,267,163,244,109 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.`

Comment: The connection string is correct. which error you are getting?

Comment: @ Adeel: I have edited the question and included the error I am getting... It seems that it is a internet connection problem but my internet is working fine

Comment: check your configuration of phpMyAdmin for the correct address of your MySQL server. If MySQL is on the same host (not necessarily true) check if MySQL is listening on a publicly available interface (could be localhost or protected by a firewall). And most important: ask on serverfault (next time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your internet connection is not going through some sort of firewall that is blocking access to port 3306.

Some companies have restricitions set on which ports can be used. Web servers use port 80 which is usually opened up to allow web browsing.  Your MySQL server is using port 3306.

Answer (score 2):

[Using JDBC with MySQL quick start guide](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3417381)

Comment: -1 Read the question carefully... the question is focused on phpmyadmin

Comment: You want to connect to the database with JDBC - phpmyadmin is just a web front-end. Connect to the database directly.

Comment: +1 for receiving -1 for ignoring phpmyadmin in this context ;)